# Insert into with two selects from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using `insert into select` to copy a row from table1 to table2, except that I need to select data from two different rows from the same table. How can this be done?

**Table 1**

```
"id"    "name"      "description"   "path"                              "country"   "status"
"1"     "Title 1"   "Description 1" "US > Consumer > Home Applicances"  "US"        "0"
"2"     "Title 2"   "Description 2" "US > Business > Legal Charges"     "UK"        "0"
```

**Table 2**

```
"id"    "name"  "description"   "path"  "newId" "newPath"   "country"   "status"
```

**Current Sql**

```
insert into table2 select null, name, description, path, country, status from table1 where id=1;
```

**Trying to do the two in one go**

```
$currentId = 1;
$newId = 2;

// This'll update columns name, description, path, country, status
insert into table2 select null, name, description, path, country, status from table1 where id=$currentId;

// This'll need to update newId, newPath same row
insert into table2 newId, newPath from table1 where id=$newId;

//Trying to achiev    
insert into table2 select null, name, description, path, country, status from table1 where id=$currentId, insert into table2 //newId, newPath  select id, path from table1 where id=$newId;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JOIN`

```sql
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.description, t1.path, t2.id, t2.path, t1.country, t1.status
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.id = $currentId AND t2.id = $newId
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d4d3/1)** demo